# Broacast receiver not receiving intent if another app registered for same intent before (PHONE_STATE)?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, phone-state-listener

My app registers in the manifest a broadcastreceiver for PHONE_STATE intent.

```
 <receiver android:name=".receiver.PhoneStateReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Everything worked fine until i installed another app which handles phone calls (in specific it records audio of phone calls). From that moment my registered receiver does not fire every time. If i remote the second app all returns to be ok.
I assume that this app (as mine) registers a broadcastreceiver for PHONE_STATE intent. Is it possible that this app "consumes" the broadcastreceiver and so it will not fire mine?

Answer (score 0):

i assume that the other broadcast consumer has called the [abortBroadcast()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#abortBroadcast()) method, that `... will prevent any other broadcast receivers from receiving the broadcast.`

Comment: Is there a system call to check if any app registered the broadcast (PHONE_STATE)  and if so warn the user that app can have problems managing calls ?

Comment: you can give your receiver a higher priority using the [android:priority](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestIntentFilter_priority) attribute of the matching intent-filter to make shure that you receiver is called before the other

Comment: Thank you @k3b it could be the better solution! i'll give it a try!